# How to remove apex.widget.waitPopup() when ui dialog opens

Tags: jquery-ui, oracle-apex, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to remove waitPopup() when "value required" error is displayed. (Correct errors before saving.)
Do you have any suggestions?

I have DA Before Page Submit:

```
$('body').append('<div class="apex_wait_overlay"/>');
vWait = apex.widget.waitPopup();
```

I already have remove when validation error appears. (jQuery Selector -> #APEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)

```
try{
  vWait.remove();
  $('body').children('div.apex_wait_overlay').remove(); 
}
catch(e){}
```

It would be nice if it was possible on ui dialog too.

> [waitPopup blocks clicking on dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPuIG.png)

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to close the wait popup when a dialog appears? What made the dialog appear?

Comment: Yes i want to remove the popup. Dialog is triggerd by clicking on submit button when page item has "Value Required" set to ON and leaving the item empty. Using Oracle APEX 19.2

Comment: All I need is to catch the moment when Dialog appears...